# Check if the value is zero will not insert in to database but if not zero will insert in to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i check if the value is zero will not insert in to database but if not zero will insert in to database ?

Here is my code snippet to make things more clearer :

```
    $SearchData = $this->redis->hmget($searchCohortKey, $DateRange);
    $NaturalClickData = $this->redis->hmget($naturalClickCohortKey, $DateRange);
    $AdClickData = $this->redis->hmget($adClickCohortKey, $DateRange);
    $uninstallData = $this->redis->hmget($uninstallKey, $DateRange);
    $count = count($DateRange);

   for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
         $dataRedis = array(
            'app_id' => $appId,
            'searches' => empty($SearchData[$i]) ? 0 : $SearchData[$i],
            'clicks' => empty($NaturalClickData[$i]) ? 0 : $NaturalClickData[$i],
            'adclicks' => empty($AdClickData[$i]) ? 0 :$AdClickData[$i],
            'uninstalls' => empty($uninstallData[$i]) ? 0 : $uninstallData[$i],
            'date' => $DateRange[$i],
            'key' => $searchCohortKey
        );
        $this->redis_search_value_model->insert($dataRedis);
   }
```

I just need to save values that is not zero or null in the database

Comment: `if ($x !=0) ....`

Comment: Your code doesn't make it any clearer but makes it worse. You seem to be inserting to redis rather than mysql

Comment: this ($this->redis_search_value_model->insert($dataRedis);) is only a mysql function not redis

Comment: its not a redis insert function

Comment: `array_filter($dataRedis);` if you just want to clean out the zero values. `if (count(array_filter($dataRedis)) == count($dataRedis)) { ... }` if you only want to save records that have no zero values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but here's what I think you are looking to achieve, you can modify the condition according to what you need.

```
$SearchData = $this->redis->hmget($searchCohortKey, $DateRange);
    $NaturalClickData = $this->redis->hmget($naturalClickCohortKey, $DateRange);
    $AdClickData = $this->redis->hmget($adClickCohortKey, $DateRange);
    $uninstallData = $this->redis->hmget($uninstallKey, $DateRange);
    $count = count($DateRange);

   for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
         $dataRedis = array(
            'app_id' => $appId,
            'searches' => empty($SearchData[$i]) ? 0 : $SearchData[$i],
            'clicks' => empty($NaturalClickData[$i]) ? 0 : $NaturalClickData[$i],
            'adclicks' => empty($AdClickData[$i]) ? 0 :$AdClickData[$i],
            'uninstalls' => empty($uninstallData[$i]) ? 0 : $uninstallData[$i],
            'date' => $DateRange[$i],
            'key' => $searchCohortKey
        );
        /*Here's the code to  check if the values are  not  zero, 
     it won't insert the data if  even of the 'searches' Or 'clicks' or adclicks
     have a value of 0*/

        if($dataRedis['searches'] != 0 && $dataRedis['clicks'] != 0 && $dataRedis['adclicks'] != 0)
        {
            $this->redis_search_value_model->insert($dataRedis);
        }
   }
```